# Modscan64 gives Timeout Errors for all responses

Tags: modbus-tcp

I am using Modscan64 to poll a service using TCP. I always receive this message:

```
** MODBUS Message TIME-OUT **
```

- I connect to loopback 127.0.0.1.
- I have tried with function 3 (holding register) and function 4 (input register), using length 2 and address 0001.
- My service (coded in Python using twisted for TCP) receives the request, properly interprets the bytes, processes it and sends a response.
- The response I send is received by MODSCAN as verified in the "Show Traffic" mode. The bytes in the response match what my service sent.

Is timeout really the issue?

How do I change the timeout? I see no settings for TCP Timeout. (googling explains how to set it for RTU only.)

If it is not really a timout, then what?

Here is a typical request / response:

```
01 00 00 00 00 06 01 04 00 00 00 02 04 04 42 ca 00 00
```

**Request (12 bytes):**

- First two bytes **01 00** are a counter that increments for each request.
- First seven bytes are the TCP header: **01 00 00 00 00 06 01**
- The next five bytes are the MODBUS request: **04 00 00 00 02**
- In the request, 04 is function code for read input register
- In the request, the next two bytes 00 00 are the address to read
- In the request, the final two bytes are 00 02 for the quantity of registers to read

**Response (6 bytes):**

- The MODBUS response is the last six bytes: **04 04 42 ca 00 00**
- The response echoes the function **04** to mean not an error
- The response then has **04** for number of bytes to follow
- The response then has **42 ca 00 00** which is single precision for 101.0 (the simulated temperature value being tested)

Does MODSCAN expect a TCP envelope in the response?

Do I need to do something to indicate byte order?

Answer (score 1):

There is a MODBUS spec and a MODBUS implementation guide. The first is less detailed and was what I was using. The second has more details, including crucial information:

MODBUS responses need to have an MBAP header, just like the requests.

See section 3.1.2 of: https://modbus.org/docs/Modbus_Messaging_Implementation_Guide_V1_0b.pdf